# database NOT NULL constraint failed Django error

Tags: python, django

I want an option to show which user adds a book to my website and I checked that the user is signed up but I got this error.

Models:

```py
class Books(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    book_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='books  covers/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} by {self.author}.'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book_detail', args=[self.id])
```

Views:

```
class AddBook(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Books
    form_class = AddBookForm
    template_name = 'books/add_book.html'
```

I got that error...:

```
IntegrityError at /books/add_book/
NOT NULL constraint failed: books_books.user_id
```

Comment: From the error, it can be seen that the "NOT NULL" constraint on the user_id field of the Books model, meaning that it cannot be null when saving a new book object. In your "AddBook" view, you haven't assigned the logged-in user to the user field of the Books model instance before saving it, hence the user_id field is not being populated, resulting in the integrity constraint failure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem originates from the `Books` model class, specifically with the `ForeignKey` field user. By default, Django requires a ForeignKey field to have a value; it cannot be `NULL`. In your `AddBook` view class, when a book instance is being created, the user field is inadvertently left as `NULL`, which violates the database's `NOT NULL` constraint for that field.

To fix this issue you need to override the `form_valid` method in your `AddBook` class to include the current user's information as the value for the user field like this:

`Views`:

```
class AddBook(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Books
    form_class = AddBookForm
    template_name = 'books/add_book.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user # Fetch and assign the logged in user as user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This will fix `database NOT NULL constraint` issue you are having.

Comment: Thank you from the bottom of my heart bro it worked and solved my problem❤️❤️